# Additional properties is not shown in build.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, application.properties

I used **mvn clean package spring-boot:build-info -DskipTests** command to generate build-info.properties in the folder target/classes/META-INF. But it was showing only the default properties not the additional properties mentioned.

I used the following plugin in the pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProperties>
                      <java.source>11</java.source>
                    </additionalProperties>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
```